# Php writing to file - empty?

Tags: php, file

I've been struggling with writing a single string into a file.
I'm using just a simple code under Slackware 13:

```
$fp = fopen('/my/absolute/path/data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'just a testing string...');
fclose($fp);
```

The file gets created (if it's not already created) but it's empty ?!
The directory in which this file is written is owned by apache's user & group (daemon.daemon) and has 0777 permissions. 
This has never happened to me before. I'm curious what's the reason I'm not able to write inside the file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code itself is definitely okay.

Comment: @Boris... damn ... I hate that thing... :D That was the problem... Apparently I got full with logs... thank you all for helping :)

Comment: P.S. Write it as an answer to the question :)

Comment: Good call Boris. Weird that PHP didn't produce any errors to indicate that the write failed due to lack of disk space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `$ df -h`

It probably means your disk is full.

Comment: Awesome catch, from bitter experience I guess? :)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you could check the return values:

```
$fp = fopen('/my/absolute/path/data.txt', 'w');

// $fp -> manual: "Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error."
if ($fp) {
    $bytes_written = fwrite($fp, 'just a testing string...');

    if ($bytes_written) {
        echo "$bytes_written bytes written!\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error while writing!\n"
    }

    $success = fclose($fp);

    if ($success) {
         echo "File successfully closed!\n";
    } else {
         echo "Error on closing!\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "No filepointer ressource!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using file_put_conents($file_name, $file_cotents);
And to retrieve content: file_get_contents($file_name);

Code looks cleaner too.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php and
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: I tired that before posting the question. The result is the same - empty file.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something is happening to the script/file before the file is closed. Check if there are any other processes that try to access the file (you can use `lsof`). Also try writing to a new file to see if the same thing occurs.

Also, check the return value on `fclose()` to make sure the file is being closed successfully.